# How to create a new column in R using if statements?

Tags: r, dataframe

Df1:

```
    Gene  Value  Label
    geneA  2    NA
    geneB  3    NA
    geneC  4    NA
    geneD  5    NA
```

Df2:

```
    Gene
    geneA
    geneD
```

I want to write script to say that if Df1$Gene is present in Df2$Gene, then replace "NA" in Df1$Label with that gene name.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Df1 <- data.frame(Gene = paste0("Gene",LETTERS[1:4]), Value = 2:5, Label = NA)
Df2 <- data.frame(Gene = c("GeneA", "GeneD"))
Df1[Df1$Gene %in% Df2$Gene, ]['Label'] <- Df2$Gene
Df1
```